# Error Add New images Product in Bigcommerce via API V2

Tags: php, bigcommerce

Help me php fix code add New images to Bigcommerce 
Add New Product in Bigcommerce via API V2

```
$data_array = array(
    'name'=>'product name', 
    "type"=> "physical",
    'description' =>'description of product', 
    'price' =>'21.98', 
    'retail_price' =>'21.98', 
    'weight' =>'0.5', 
    'depth' =>'12', 
    "categories" => [23],
    "availability"=> "available", 
    'inventory_level' =>'0',
    "videos" =>  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNxnvMbmvN0",
    "image_file" =>  "http://www.codefixup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/add-products-in-jet-com-via-api.png"
);
```

> error: 400 The field 'videos' cannot be written to. Please remove it from your request before trying again.
>   or: 400The field 'image_file' is not supported by this resource.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#create-a-product <= no show add image

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about videos, but the image file should be local, not a URL.

Comment: Hello Difster => image_file  string  When specifying a product image, the image_file should be specified as either: a path to an image already uploaded via WebDAV to the import directory (with the path relative to the import directory); or a URL to an image accessible on the internet. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#product-images